# Сервис не запускается и выдает ошибку

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

При нажатии на элемент списка должен запускаться сервис и включаться проигрыватель, но этого не происходит, а при последующем повороте экрана приложение благополучно вылетает. И получается так, что код который день назад отлично работал сегодня уже не работает (Код изменениям не подвергался). В чем может быть ошибка?

Service class

```
public class PlayService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener{

    private String media;
    private String KEY_EXTRA="key_song";

    public MediaPlayer backgroundPlayer;
    public AudioManager audioManager;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
    private int length = 0;

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {

        public  PlayService getService(){
            return PlayService.this;
        }
    }

    public PlayService() {}

    private  void initializeMp(){
        backgroundPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

        backgroundPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        backgroundPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);

        backgroundPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                onError(backgroundPlayer,what,extra);
                return true;
            }
        });

        backgroundPlayer.reset();    
        backgroundPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            backgroundPlayer.setDataSource(media);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            stopSelf();
        }
        backgroundPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();    
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {
            media = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA);
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            stopSelf();
        }

        if (requestAudioFocus() == false) {
            stopSelf();
        }

        if(media!=null && media!=""){
            initializeMp();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }    

    public void onPause(){
        if(backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()){
            backgroundPlayer.pause();
            length=backgroundPlayer.getCurrentPosition();    
        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic(){
        if(!backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()){
            backgroundPlayer.seekTo(length);
            backgroundPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void playMusic(){
        if (!backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            backgroundPlayer.start();
        } 
    }

    public void stopMusic(){
        if(backgroundPlayer == null) return;

        if (backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            backgroundPlayer.stop();
            backgroundPlayer.release();
            backgroundPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private boolean requestAudioFocus() {

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean removeAudioFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(backgroundPlayer != null){
            try{
                stopMusic();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        removeAudioFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if(backgroundPlayer != null){
            try{
                backgroundPlayer.stop();
                backgroundPlayer.release();
            }finally {
                backgroundPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focus) {

        switch (focus){
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:

                if (backgroundPlayer == null) initializeMp();
                else if (!backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) backgroundPlayer.start();
                backgroundPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:

                if (backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) backgroundPlayer.stop();
                backgroundPlayer.release();
                backgroundPlayer = null;
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:

                if (backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) backgroundPlayer.pause();
                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:

                if (backgroundPlayer.isPlaying()) backgroundPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopMusic();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       playMusic();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }
}
```

Подключаюсь так

```
private ServiceConnection Scon =new ServiceConnection(){

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, final IBinder
                binder) {
            mServ = ((PlayService.ServiceBinder)binder).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServ = null;
        }
    };

    public void doBindService(){
        getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity(),PlayService.class),
                Scon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    public void doUnbindService(){
        if(mIsBound){
            getActivity().unbindService(Scon);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Приведите логи ошибки

Comment: Вопрос решен. Сервис просто был переписан заново!

Comment: Что значит переписан? Так вы же сказали, что код не подвергался к изменениям

Comment: ТС сам не знает что произошло.

Comment: Код был переписан после того как появилась ошибка. А так то да я и сам до сих пор не понял  в чем была проблема.